# Laravel 9 passing data to Javascript file

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I want to pass the data from the Laravel controller to the JS file then show it in the Laravel Blade view as it appears in the code
in this `var dtUserTable = $('.user-list-table'),`

`user-list-table` is a class that is called on the blade.php page. As it appears this is the call of it, how can I return the data from or pass the data from the Laravel controller to the JS file then show it in the blade.php file?

**app-user-list.js**

```
$(function () {
  'use strict';

  var dtUserTable = $('.user-list-table'),
    newUserSidebar = $('.new-user-modal'),
    newUserForm = $('.add-new-user'),
    statusObj = {
      1: { title: 'Pending', class: 'badge-light-warning' },
      2: { title: 'Active', class: 'badge-light-success' },
      3: { title: 'Inactive', class: 'badge-light-secondary' }
    };

  var assetPath = '../../../app-assets/',
    userView = 'app-user-view.html',
    userEdit = 'app-user-edit.html';
  if ($('body').attr('data-framework') === 'laravel') {
    assetPath = $('body').attr('data-asset-path');
    userView = assetPath + 'app/user/view';
    userEdit = assetPath + 'app/user/edit';
  }

  // Users List datatable
  if (dtUserTable.length) {
    dtUserTable.DataTable({
      ajax: assetPath + 'data/user-list.json', // JSON file to add data
      columns: [
        // columns according to JSON
        { data: 'responsive_id' },
        { data: 'full_name' },
        { data: 'email' },
        { data: 'role' },
        { data: 'current_plan' },
        { data: 'status' },
        { data: '' }
      ],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          // For Responsive
          className: 'control',
          orderable: false,
          responsivePriority: 2,
          targets: 0
        },
        {
          // User full name and username
          targets: 1,
          responsivePriority: 4,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var $name = full['full_name'],
              $uname = full['username'],
              $image = full['avatar'];
            if ($image) {
              // For Avatar image
              var $output =
                '<img src="' + assetPath + 'images/avatars/' + $image + '" alt="Avatar" height="32" width="32">';
            } else {
              // For Avatar badge
              var stateNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
              var states = ['success', 'danger', 'warning', 'info', 'dark', 'primary', 'secondary'];
              var $state = states[stateNum],
                $name = full['full_name'],
                $initials = $name.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
              $initials = (($initials.shift() || '') + ($initials.pop() || '')).toUpperCase();
              $output = '<span class="avatar-content">' + $initials + '</span>';
            }
            var colorClass = $image === '' ? ' bg-light-' + $state + ' ' : '';
            // Creates full output for row
            var $row_output =
              '<div class="d-flex justify-content-left align-items-center">' +
              '<div class="avatar-wrapper">' +
              '<div class="avatar ' +
              colorClass +
              ' mr-1">' +
              $output +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="d-flex flex-column">' +
              '<a href="' +
              userView +
              '" class="user_name text-truncate"><span class="font-weight-bold">' +
              $name +
              '</span></a>' +
              '<small class="emp_post text-muted">@' +
              $uname +
              '</small>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>';
            return $row_output;
          }
        },
        {
          // User Role
          targets: 3,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var $role = full['role'];
            var roleBadgeObj = {
              Subscriber: feather.icons['user'].toSvg({ class: 'font-medium-3 text-primary mr-50' }),
              Author: feather.icons['settings'].toSvg({ class: 'font-medium-3 text-warning mr-50' }),
              Maintainer: feather.icons['database'].toSvg({ class: 'font-medium-3 text-success mr-50' }),
              Editor: feather.icons['edit-2'].toSvg({ class: 'font-medium-3 text-info mr-50' }),
              Admin: feather.icons['slack'].toSvg({ class: 'font-medium-3 text-danger mr-50' })
            };
            return "<span class='text-truncate align-middle'>" + roleBadgeObj[$role] + $role + '</span>';
          }
        },
        {
          // User Status
          targets: 5,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var $status = full['status'];

            return (
              '<span class="badge badge-pill ' +
              statusObj[$status].class +
              '" text-capitalized>' +
              statusObj[$status].title +
              '</span>'
            );
          }
        },
        {
          // Actions
          targets: -1,
          title: 'Actions',
          orderable: false,
          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return (
              '<div class="btn-group">' +
              '<a class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle hide-arrow" data-toggle="dropdown">' +
              feather.icons['more-vertical'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4' }) +
              '</a>' +
              '<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">' +
              '<a href="' +
              userView +
              '" class="dropdown-item">' +
              feather.icons['file-text'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) +
              'Details</a>' +
              '<a href="' +
              userEdit +
              '" class="dropdown-item">' +
              feather.icons['archive'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) +
              'Edit</a>' +
              '<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-item delete-record">' +
              feather.icons['trash-2'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) +
              'Delete</a></div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>'
            );
          }
        }
      ],
      order: [[2, 'desc']],
      dom:
        '<"d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center header-actions mx-1 row mt-75"' +
        '<"col-lg-12 col-xl-6" l>' +
        '<"col-lg-12 col-xl-6 pl-xl-75 pl-0"<"dt-action-buttons text-xl-right text-lg-left text-md-right text-left d-flex align-items-center justify-content-lg-end align-items-center flex-sm-nowrap flex-wrap mr-1"<"mr-1"f>B>>' +
        '>t' +
        '<"d-flex justify-content-between mx-2 row mb-1"' +
        '<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"i>' +
        '<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"p>' +
        '>',
      language: {
        sLengthMenu: 'Show _MENU_',
        search: 'Search',
        searchPlaceholder: 'Search..'
      },
      // Buttons with Dropdown
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Add New User',
          className: 'add-new btn btn-primary mt-50',
          attr: {
            'data-toggle': 'modal',
            'data-target': '#modals-slide-in'
          },
          init: function (api, node, config) {
            $(node).removeClass('btn-secondary');
          }
        }
      ],
      // For responsive popup
      responsive: {
        details: {
          display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
            header: function (row) {
              var data = row.data();
              return 'Details of ' + data['full_name'];
            }
          }),
          type: 'column',
          renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll({
            tableClass: 'table',
            columnDefs: [
              {
                targets: 2,
                visible: false
              },
              {
                targets: 3,
                visible: false
              }
            ]
          })
        }
      },
      language: {
        paginate: {
          // remove previous & next text from pagination
          previous: '&nbsp;',
          next: '&nbsp;'
        }
      },
      initComplete: function () {
        // Adding role filter once table initialized
        this.api()
          .columns(3)
          .every(function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $(
              '<select id="UserRole" class="form-control text-capitalize mb-md-0 mb-2"><option value=""> Select Role </option></select>'
            )
              .appendTo('.user_role')
              .on('change', function () {
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
              });

            column
              .data()
              .unique()
              .sort()
              .each(function (d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '" class="text-capitalize">' + d + '</option>');
              });
          });
        // Adding plan filter once table initialized
        this.api()
          .columns(4)
          .every(function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $(
              '<select id="UserPlan" class="form-control text-capitalize mb-md-0 mb-2"><option value=""> Select Plan </option></select>'
            )
              .appendTo('.user_plan')
              .on('change', function () {
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
              });

            column
              .data()
              .unique()
              .sort()
              .each(function (d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '" class="text-capitalize">' + d + '</option>');
              });
          });
        // Adding status filter once table initialized
        this.api()
          .columns(5)
          .every(function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $(
              '<select id="FilterTransaction" class="form-control text-capitalize mb-md-0 mb-2xx"><option value=""> Select Status </option></select>'
            )
              .appendTo('.user_status')
              .on('change', function () {
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
              });

            column
              .data()
              .unique()
              .sort()
              .each(function (d, j) {
                select.append(
                  '<option value="' +
                    statusObj[d].title +
                    '" class="text-capitalize">' +
                    statusObj[d].title +
                    '</option>'
                );
              });
          });
      }
    });
  }

  // Check Validity
  function checkValidity(el) {
    if (el.validate().checkForm()) {
      submitBtn.attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
      submitBtn.attr('disabled', true);
    }
  }

  // Form Validation
  if (newUserForm.length) {
    newUserForm.validate({
      errorClass: 'error',
      rules: {
        'user-fullname': {
          required: true
        },
        'user-name': {
          required: true
        },
        'user-email': {
          required: true
        }
      }
    });

    newUserForm.on('submit', function (e) {
      var isValid = newUserForm.valid();
      e.preventDefault();
      if (isValid) {
        newUserSidebar.modal('hide');
      }
    });
  }

  // To initialize tooltip with body container
  $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]',
    container: 'body'
  });
});
```

**Blade/View**

```
@extends('panel.index')
@section('css-con')

<!-- BEGIN: Vendor CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/css/tables/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/css/tables/datatable/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/css/tables/datatable/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css')}}">
<!-- END: Vendor CSS-->

<!-- BEGIN: Page CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/css/plugins/forms/form-validation.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('app-assets/css/pages/app-user.css')}}">
<!-- END: Page CSS-->
@endsection

@section('content')
    <!-- users list start -->
    <section class="app-user-list">
        <!-- users filter start -->
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">Search Filter</h5>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mx-50 row pt-0 pb-2">
                <div class="col-md-4 user_role"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 user_plan"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 user_status"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- users filter end -->
        <!-- list section start -->
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-datatable table-responsive pt-0">
                <table class="user-list-table table">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>User</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Role</th>
                            <th>Plan</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal to add new user starts-->
            <div class="modal modal-slide-in new-user-modal fade" id="modals-slide-in">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <form class="add-new-user modal-content pt-0">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">×</button>
                        <div class="modal-header mb-1">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New User</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body flex-grow-1">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname">Full Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control dt-full-name" id="basic-icon-default-fullname" placeholder="John Doe" name="user-fullname" aria-label="John Doe" aria-describedby="basic-icon-default-fullname2" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-uname">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" id="basic-icon-default-uname" class="form-control dt-uname" placeholder="Web Developer" aria-label="jdoe1" aria-describedby="basic-icon-default-uname2" name="user-name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" id="basic-icon-default-email" class="form-control dt-email" placeholder="john.doe@example.com" aria-label="john.doe@example.com" aria-describedby="basic-icon-default-email2" name="user-email" />
                                <small class="form-text text-muted"> You can use letters, numbers & periods </small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label" for="user-role">User Role</label>
                                <select id="user-role" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="subscriber">Subscriber</option>
                                    <option value="editor">Editor</option>
                                    <option value="maintainer">Maintainer</option>
                                    <option value="author">Author</option>
                                    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1 data-submit">Submit</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal to add new user Ends-->
        </div>
        <!-- list section end -->
    </section>
    <!-- users list ends -->

@endsection




@section('jc-con')


   <!-- BEGIN: Page Vendor JS-->
   <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
   <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.bootstrap4.min.js')}}"></script>
   <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/dataTables.responsive.min.js')}}"></script>
   <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/responsive.bootstrap4.js')}}"></script>
   <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.buttons.min.js')}}"></script>
   <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js')}}"></script>
   <script src="{{asset('app-assets/vendors/js/forms/validation/jquery.validate.min.js')}}"></script>
   <!-- END: Page Vendor JS-->



   <!-- BEGIN: Page JS-->
   <script src="{{asset('app-assets/js/scripts/pages/app-user-list.js')}}"></script>
   <!-- END: Page JS-->


@endsection
```

Below is the function that I call when I want to get the data in the Laravel controller.

```
public function list()
{   
    $data = DB::table('users')->get();

    return view('content.apps.user.user-list',compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

blade

```
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        //line chart
        var line = new Morris.Line({
            element: 'line-chart',
            resize: true,
            data: [
                @foreach ($data as $value)
                {
                    ym: "{{ $value->year }}-{{ $value->month }}", sum: "{{ $value->sum }}"
                },
                @endforeach
            ],
            xkey: 'ym',
            ykeys: ['sum'],
            labels: ['@lang('site.total')'],
            lineWidth: 2,
            gridTextFamily: 'Open Sans',
            gridTextSize: 10
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: not working this way to pass it to the js file then it will be by the class dynamic there